# Get all rows in the "current" table, and not from child tables

Tags: jquery

How can you get all rows in a table without getting the rows in child tables?

```
var rows = $('tr', tbl);
```

This will return ALL `<tr>` tags, including all rows in child tables.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
var rows = $('#tblID > tbody > tr')
```

The [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) will get the table's `<tbody>` element and consequently get the `<tr>` elements that are direct children of the table's tbody.

If you already have a table object:

```
var rows = $(tbl).find('> tbody > tr');
```

Or:

```
var rows = $(tbl).children('tbody').children('tr');
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/8pecr0kd/).

Comment: - and if you already got the table object like in my example?

Comment: Out of interest will this cope with intermediate tbody elements?

Comment: yes.. what about the tbody.. children('tr') returns an incorrect value

Comment: If you have a `<tbody>` element, then you should factor that into the selector. Something like: `$(tbl).children('tbody').children('tr')`.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo: Every table will contain a `tBody` element. That's automatically inserted.

Comment: @Felix You're absolutely right. I should've tested this better.

Answer (score 4):

```
var count = $('#tableID').rows;
```

It works, because the selector will return a HTMLTableElement object.

Comment: `$('#tableID').get(0).rows`

Answer (score 2):

Probably:

```
var rows = $("#tableid>tr");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the count of rows, you can simply use:

```
var table = document.getElementById('tableID');  
table.rows.length;
```

Or you can use direct children selector:

```
$('table > tbody > tr').each(function(index, tr) {} );
```