# Get Parent Table <tr> Length Only

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a nested table...

```
<table id="Table1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Row 1 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Row 2
            <table id="Table2">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                      Row 1 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I use jQuery to find the `tr` row count...

```
var RowCount = $("#Table1 tr").length;
```

How do I write jquery to find ONLY the row count of the parent table `Table1` and not the combined nested `Table2` ? For example: the result I would be looking for would be RowCount = 2 and not RowCount = 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Using the DOM property:
var rowCount = $("#Table1")[0].rows.length;
// Or:
var rowCount = $("#Table1 > tbody > tr").length;
// Using the child selector, "parent > child"
```

I've renamed `RowCount` to `rowCount`, because only consstructor names start with a capital, by convention.

Comment: It actually is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012469/get-all-rows-in-the-current-table-and-not-from-child-tables). I wonder how that answer worked though...

Answer (score 1):

the line below uses jQuery's .children to get immediate descendants of the selected objects, and optionally filter results with a selector argument.. In your case, table1 and "tr" respectively.

`var rowCount = $("#Table1").children("tr").length;`

Comment: `tr`s are *never* the children of a `table` element. Browsers always insert a `tbody` element automatically.

Comment: @Felix figures, i'm busy typing up a comment, edit a typo in my answer, and my comment becomes irrelevant.  *sigh* anyway.  "Always try to build a <table><thead/><tfoot/><tbody/></table> with all those elements in that order.  i've been told it helps most browsers render the table faster.