# How can i create a "Select all" button for a table

Tags: javascript, php, html, button

I am creating an table for an website. The website returns its values in an table. i need to copy all values from the table td's, and paste them in excel. is there a way to make a "select all" button, so that i only need to press ctrl+c? Instead of dragging my mouse all the way down the table.

[image: I want outcome to be like this (if I press the button)]

Code of the table i used here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Select all test</h2>
    <button type="button">Select all</button>
    <table style="width:80%">
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Henk</td>
            <td>Bakker</td>
            <td>46</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fedde</td>
            <td>hooghouts</td>
            <td>67</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: you try that with javascript or jquery [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012469/get-all-rows-in-the-current-table-and-not-from-child-tables)

Comment: If it is a basic HTML table, you can directly import it into excel by using `menu - data - import from web`, then copy pasting the URL and selecting the correct table. If all you're doing is making shortcuts for manual operations, this was easier to teach my users than actually creating a script to select, then press ctrl-c, go to excel, paste the data, reformat the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS:

```
function selectElementContents(el) {
        var body = document.body, range, sel;
        if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
            range = document.createRange();
            sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            try {
                range.selectNodeContents(el);
                sel.addRange(range);
            } catch (e) {
                range.selectNode(el);
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
        } else if (body.createTextRange) {
            range = body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(el);
            range.select();
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<table id="tableId" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Heading 1</th><th>Heading 2</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>cell 1</td><td>cell 2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" value="select table" onclick="selectElementContents( document.getElementById('tableId') );">
```

It should work ;)

Link from:
**[Select a complete table with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044616/select-a-complete-table-with-javascript-to-be-copied-to-clipboard)**

Comment: is it also possible to only select and copy the tbody, but to keel the layout? so it also copies the border and stuff? because now if i paste it in excel it goed in 1 cell